# Android swipe and addforce unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, swipe

I am working on 2D infinite runner. I have below code to take input from screen swipe to jump, slide and run fast. I am providing jumpHeight from editor and value is 500 with frame rate of 30. Code works fine generally but sometimes player jumps too high for up swipe. Similar code works as expected if input is from Keyboard. Why this is happening is beyond my understanding of unity. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float ForwardSpeed = 3.7f; //moves player in forward direction
    public float speedOffset = 0.0f; //offset speed of player
    public float JumpHeight = 250; //moves player in verticle direction
    bool grounded = false; //checks if player is grounded or not
    public Transform groundCheck;
    float groundCheckRadius = 0.3f; //radius of groundcheck circle to check grounded bool
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    Vector2 fingerStart;
    Vector2 fingerEnd;

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                fingerStart = touch.position;
                fingerEnd = touch.position;
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                fingerEnd = touch.position;
                if (Mathf.Abs(fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y) > 50)//Vertical swipe
                {
                    if (fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y > 50)//up swipe
                    {
                        Jump();
                    }
                    else if (fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y < -50)//Down swipe
                    {
                        //Slide();
                    }
                    fingerStart = touch.position;
                }
            }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
            {
                RunFast();
            }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                fingerEnd = touch.position;
                if (Mathf.Abs(fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y) > 50)//Vertical swipe
                {
                    if (fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y > 50)//up swipe
                    {
                        Jump();
                    }
                    else if (fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y < -50)//Down swipe
                    {
                        //Slide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            speedOffset = 2.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            speedOffset = 0.0f;
        }


        if (grounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            grounded = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpHeight));
        }

        //check if circle overlaps with ground layer
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, groundLayer);
        //Debug.Log(grounded);


    }



    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //set players forward velocityto forward speed variable
        Vector2 PlayerForwardvelocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
        // Vector2 PlayerJumpHeight = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce()
        PlayerForwardvelocity.x = ForwardSpeed + speedOffset;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = PlayerForwardvelocity;
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (grounded)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpHeight));
            speedOffset = 0.0f;
        }

    }

    void RunFast()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            speedOffset = 2.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            speedOffset = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upload a complete version of the code that compiles. I need so that I will take a look at it by debugging it. You can remove other functions that are not relevant.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks for the response. I have edited the code. Just attach this to a player object. I am facing problem with different gestures for up swipe like a quick swipe, slow drag, long drag. Specially for a long up drag player jumps really high.

Comment: One thing come to my mind. On my project i've got problems with AddForce, i cant explain exactly but it looks like force is add in wrong situation when some force is already added, there could be a problem. Try to reset eg. velocity on Y just before you add jump force.

Comment: @PawełMarecki Can you please explain a little. Velocity is added in x direction while force is added in y direction. And this code works fine when input is from keyboard. If you can tell me in detail i can try out the solution.

Comment: @RxC Hmm another thing. You testing swipe on android device and keyboard input in Unity Editor?

Comment: @PawełMarecki Yes. Somehow distance and time of drag is affecting the height of jump. not sure why as the force applied is always the same.

Comment: @RxC Consider this, PC (Unity Editor) can run game really fast eg 100 FPS, but android device should display about 60 FPS. This could be matters when you call `AddForce` in `Update()`, one thing. Install Unity Remote on your android device. Unity Remote allows you to debug touch input in Unity Editor, so you can check same code in Unity and on device.

Comment: @PawełMarecki I tried unity remote already and it produces same results as actual android build for this problem. Situation is only better when i apply really low amount of force like 100f but that causes player to jump really low sometime to not jump at all which will be really irritating for anyone playing the game. :(

Comment: @RxC Last thing that came to my mind is maybe `Jump()` is executed more than once. You can also try to move every `AddForce` to `FixedUpdate()` like eg. In `Update()` when you want to jump set some bool value, and check that value in `FixedUpdate()` and then execute `Jump()`. I'm running out of ideas :(

Comment: Hey, Currently I am in office I will check when I reach home in the evening. I noticed that grounded is always true because I never reset it in jump function call. I will try it in the evening and post the result.

Comment: @Programmer You are awesome man. Your timer suggestion did the trick and now it works like charm. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RxC you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your code.

Your first problem lies in this line of code:

```
 grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, groundLayer);
```

This line of code is failing. `grounded` is always `true`. Because of this, jump is called too many times while player is not grounded.

Replace this line of code with

```
 Collider2D playerCollider = gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
 grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(playerCollider.transform.position, 1, groundLayer);
```

**OR**

```
Collider2D playerCollider = gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
grounded = playerCollider.IsTouchingLayers(groundLayer.value);
```

Another problem with your code is a `false` report.Sometimes, collider overlapping returns `true` even if it is `false`. I tried moving that part of code to LateUpdate function but that didn't fix it.

You can fix it by implementing a timer. The timer resets to **0** and starts counting to **0.5** whenever player jumps. Don't jump when timer has not reached the value it is counting to. `.5 to 1` is a perfect value for this. Increment the timer with `Time.deltaTime`. Below is your whole code with timer and fixes.

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float ForwardSpeed = 3.7f; //moves player in forward direction
    public float speedOffset = 0.0f; //offset speed of player
    public float JumpHeight = 250; //moves player in verticle direction
    bool grounded = false; //checks if player is grounded or not
    public Transform groundCheck;
    float groundCheckRadius = 0.3f; //radius of groundcheck circle to check grounded bool
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    Vector2 fingerStart;
    Vector2 fingerEnd;

    public float resetTimer = 0.5f; //.5 second
    float timerCounter = 0;
    Collider2D playerCollider = null;

    Rigidbody2D playerRigidBody;


    void Start()
    {
        playerRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerCollider = gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                fingerStart = touch.position;
                fingerEnd = touch.position;
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                fingerEnd = touch.position;
                if (Mathf.Abs(fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y) > 50)//Vertical swipe
                {
                    if (fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y > 50)//up swipe
                    {
                        Jump();
                    }
                    else if (fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y < -50)//Down swipe
                    {
                        //Slide();
                    }
                    fingerStart = touch.position;
                }
            }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
            {
                RunFast();
            }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                fingerEnd = touch.position;
                if (Mathf.Abs(fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y) > 50)//Vertical swipe
                {
                    if (fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y > 50)//up swipe
                    {
                        Jump();
                    }
                    else if (fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y < -50)//Down swipe
                    {
                        //Slide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            speedOffset = 2.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            speedOffset = 0.0f;
        }


        if (grounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            grounded = false;
            playerRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpHeight));
        }

        //check if circle overlaps with ground layer
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(playerCollider.transform.position, 1, groundLayer);
        //OR Use grounded = playerCollider.IsTouchingLayers(groundLayer.value);

        //Increment Timer if it is still less than resetTimer
        if (timerCounter < resetTimer)
        {
            timerCounter += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //set players forward velocityto forward speed variable
        Vector2 PlayerForwardvelocity = playerRigidBody.velocity;
        // Vector2 PlayerJumpHeight = playerRigidBody.AddForce()
        PlayerForwardvelocity.x = ForwardSpeed + speedOffset;
        playerRigidBody.velocity = PlayerForwardvelocity;
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (grounded)
        {
            //Exit if timer has not reached the required value to jump again
            if (timerCounter < resetTimer)
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed To Jump because timer has not yet reached");
                return; //Exit
            }

            timerCounter = 0; //Reset Timer

            playerRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpHeight));
            speedOffset = 0.0f;
            Debug.Log("Jumped");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not on the Ground");
        }

    }

    void RunFast()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            speedOffset = 2.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            speedOffset = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```